# Group Actions: Discontinuity

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, group-actions

Given a group action $G\curvearrowright X$.

Then it need not be a continuous one: $l_g\notin\mathcal{C}(X)$

As an example I have in mind:
$$k\in\mathbb{Z}:\quad l_k(x\in\mathbb{Z}):=x+k,\quad l_k(x\notin\mathbb{Z}):=x\quad(x\in\mathbb{R})$$

Are there standard examples though?

*Reference: This is a start-up to: [Group Actions: Orbit Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1105458/79762)*

Comment: "Most" group actions should be discontinuous. Do you have any properties in mind?

Comment: @MikeMiller: No I just thought there might be standard examples.

Comment: Well, pick any bijection $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. The vast majority - anything not described by a continuous monotonic function - are discontinuous. Then the action $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb R$, $n\cdot r := f^n(r)$, is a discontinuous group action. You can do this for every topological space that has discontinuous bijections to itself.

Comment: Ah right. Are there also standard examples a professor would show in class?

Comment: Just start with *any* nontrivial group action and then endow the set $X$ with a nonsymmetric topology. For example, declare $U\subset X$ open iff it contains a special point $x_0$ or is empty.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Would you mind posting your comment as answer, please? *(So I can check it off.)*

Comment: @MikeMiller: I will give an answer in your name. Let me know if you give one; I will delete mine then and accept yours instead.

Comment: Your answer is fine. I'm glad you found my comment helpful.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Yes, I liked yours. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For now, let me give an answer due to Mike Miller.*

*(I will delete this one if he himself will post one.)*

Choose a discontinuous bijection:
$$\varphi:\mathbb{R}\leftrightarrow\mathbb{R}:\quad\varphi\notin\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$$
Construct a group action by:
$$\mathbb{Z}\curvearrowright\mathbb{R}:\quad l_k(x):=\varphi^k(x)$$
Then the left translations are discontinuous.