# Group Actions: Orbit Space

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, group-actions

Given a group action $G\curvearrowright X$.

Consider the orbit space: $\pi:X\to X/G$

> Do continuous group actions correspond to open projections, i.e.:
>   $$l_g\in\mathcal{C}(X)\quad(g\in G)\iff\pi(U)\in\mathcal{T}_{X/G}\quad(U\in\mathcal{T}_X)$$
>   *(Note that this is a slightly different more appropriate version of continuous group actions.)*

Certainly, continuous group actions give rise to open projections since:
$$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=\bigcup_{u\in U}Gu=GU=\bigcup_{g\in G}gU=\bigcup_{g\in G}l_g(U)\in\mathcal{T}$$

Surely, the converse may hold as the following example suggests:
$$l_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}:=\mathrm{id}+k\chi_\mathbb{Z}:\quad \pi^{-1}(\pi(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon))=(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\cup\mathbb{Z}\notin\mathcal{T}_\mathbb{R}$$

Besides, the analog assertion about closed projections is wrong:
$$l_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}(x):=x+q:\quad\pi^{-1}(\pi(\{0\}^\complement))=\mathbb{Q}^\complement\notin\mathcal{T}_\mathbb{R}$$
*(That is arbitrary unions of closed sets are not closed in general.)*

Still how to prove that the converse holds true, too?

*Reference: This is a follow-up to: [Group Actions: Discontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104400/79762)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false in general, take for instance, $G\cong {\mathbb Z}$ acting on the circle via irrational rotations. Then the projection of each point to $Q=S^1/G$ is not only not closed, it is actually a dense point in $Q$.

Edit: I misread the original question as I thought you were asking about the quotient map being closed. The answer to you question is that open projection $\pi$ does not imply that the action is continuous. As an example, consider the  transitive action of the group $G$ of real numbers on itself via left translation, $G\times X\to X$, $X=G$. Now, change the topology on $X$ to make this action discontinuous (say, pick a bijection of $f: X\to [0,1]$ and equip $X$ with the preimage of the standard topology on $[0,1]$). The resulting action is no longer continuous, but the map $\pi: X\to X/G=\{p\}$ is open.

Comment: Yes but the question was wether this holds *precisely* for continuous group actions.

Comment: But besides I just realize that the projections are open *and* closed. Will add this. ;)

Comment: @Freeze_S: I guess, you are using a nonstandard notion of a continuous action, you then should add your definition.

Comment: Call a group action continuous if its left translations are continuous. *(See the assertion.)* What would be the standard definition? *(Afaik that is already the usual one.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S: the standard one is that the action map $G\times X\to X$ is a continuous map. It agrees with your definition if G is given discrete topology. Then why do you say that the example I gave is not continuous? Rotations of the circle are continuous maps.

Comment: Ok so that is considering topological groups. But your example shows something else: The projection is not necessarily closed. _(Note that being open and being closed are **not** the same.)_

Comment: Besides thanks for remembering about that - do you mind if I add this example to the thread? *(Still the question of equivalence.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S: You can surely use this example, it is very standard. I do not understand what the _question of equivalence_ is, since you now know that the quotient map for a continuous group action is always open (you wrote a proof),  but is not always closed. Incidentally, even having a _proper_ group action of a discrete group is not enough to guarantee a closed map. An example is the standard action of $Z$ on $R$.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I mean that the projection is open iff the action is continuous. The analog assertion that a projection is closed iff the action is continuous is wrong. *(Again note that being closed and being open are not complementary notions.)*

Comment: Note: This is not an answer to my question; I will check it off anyway.